# could not execute statement update

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to execute an SQL Query to update some data in a Database column, but when I run the program I get the following error:

```
Hibernate: update DeputeAppeal set FilePath=/home/oleg/DeputeAppealsFiles/1 where id=38
[ERROR] [http-bio-8080-exec-2 09:21:21] (SqlExceptionHelper.java:logExceptions:131) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/home/oleg/DeputeAppealsFiles/1 where id=38' at line 1
```

This is the method in the DAO:

```
public void editFilePathName(DeputeAppeal deputeAppeal, String filePathName) {
        Query query = sessionDao.getSession().createSQLQuery("update DeputeAppeal set FilePath=" + filePathName + " where id=" + deputeAppeal.getId());
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the single quotes for `'filePathName'` in your query:

```
Query query = sessionDao.getSession().createSQLQuery("update DeputeAppeal set FilePath=" + filePathName + " where id=" + deputeAppeal.getId());
```

Use this instead :

```
Query query = sessionDao.getSession().createSQLQuery("update DeputeAppeal set FilePath = '" + filePathName + "' where id=" + deputeAppeal.getId());
```